# Makefile with two targets and separate build folders

Tags: makefile, gnu

I am trying to use one Makefile with two similar targets and two separate build folders. The only difference between the targets is the addition of a `CFLAG` define.

Here is a snippet of what I have, however I can't get the build folder to evaluate to something different depending on the target. I used `foo` and `bar` to represent the different targets.

```
...
foo_BUILD_DIR := build_foo/
bar_BUILD_DIR := build_bar/

C_SRCS := main.c

CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Os -Wall
foo_CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -DBLE=1

C_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR),$(subst .c,.o,$(C_SRCS)))

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

foo:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ 

bar:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems to solve here.

The first is building object files in the build directories. First we write a pattern rule to build foo objects:

```
foo_BUILD_DIR := build_foo # Don't put the trailing slash in the dir name, it's a pain.

CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Os -Wall
foo_CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -DBLE=1

$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(foo_CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Once that's working perfectly, we write another rule for the bar objects:

```
$(bar_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

The second problem is tidying up what we've written so far. That `foo_CFLAGS` variable is now the only thing making these two recipes different, so let's get rid of it with a [target-specific variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: CFLAGS += -DBLE=1

$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Now we can combine the rules into one pattern rule with two targets:

```
$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: CFLAGS += -DBLE=1

$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o $(bar_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

The third problem is getting the `foo` and `bar` rules to require the right objects. Obviously this rule:

```
foo:$(OBJS)
    ...
```

won't work, we need something specific to `foo`:

```
foo: $(addprefix $(foo_BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
    ...
```

This works, but it requires us to write a `foo` rule that specifies `$(foo_BUILD_DIR)`, a `bar` rule that specifies `$(bar_BUILD_DIR)`, and so on. Is there a lazier way? All we need is to take the target (e.g. `foo`) and get it into the prerequisite list. As you know, the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$@` contains the target, but it isn't available in the prerequisite list, because the prerequisite list is expanded before a value is assigned to that variable-- *unless* we use [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion). This is an advanced technique, but it lets us do a second expansion in the later phase (escaping our variables with an extra `$` to protect them from the first expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo: $(addprefix $$($$@_BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
    ...
```

And once that's working, we can add another target, or as many as we want:

```
foo bar: $(addprefix $$($$@_BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
    ...
```

There are one or two more refinements possible, but this is enough to start with.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get this to work `foo: $(addprefix $$($$@_BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))` though without these edits: `foo: $(addprefix $(foo_BUILD_DIR)/, $(OBJS))`. The error without edits after invoking `make foo`: `make: *** No rule to make target '$($@_BUILD_DIR)/main.o', needed by 'foo'.  Stop.`

Comment: I have also noticed that following your same strategy for `LDFLAGS` incurs no effect for some reason: `$(foo_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: LDFLAGS += -Tmylinkerfile.ld`

Comment: @User3219: **I forgot to show the `.SECONDEXPANSION:` line.** Sorry about that, I'll edit.

Comment: @User3219: ...And your line seems to modify `LDFLAGS` as you intend. But why would you care about `LDFLAGS` when you build an object file?

Comment: What's the dot at the end of `foo_BUILD_DIR := build_foo.` for?

Comment: @AJM: It's to keep from getting too sure of myself. It's a typo, which I either failed to notice in testing, or added by mistake when I posted the code and perhaps added the comment. I'll edit